# Need to check if channel exists within category, and if it doesn't then make a new one in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need to check the existence of `channel1`, `channel2`, `channel3`, and `channel4` before creating them.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const disbut = require('discord-buttons');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const guild = new Discord.Guild();
const { prefix, token, categoryID } = require('./config.json');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const command = require('./command');

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The client is ready!')
});

client.login(token);

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle("Title")
 .setColor("#ff00ff")
 .setDescription("Description")
 .setFooter("Footer")
 .setImage("myimage")
 .setTimestamp()

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content == "server") {
        try {
            await message.guild.setIcon('./icon.png');
            await message.guild.setName("My Server");
            await message.guild.channels.create("channel1", { type: 'text', parent: categoryID });
            await message.guild.channels.create("channel2", { type: 'text', parent: categoryID });
            await message.guild.channels.create("channel3", { type: 'text', parent: categoryID });
            await message.guild.channels.create("channel4", { type: 'text', parent: categoryID });
            message.channel.send({embed});
        } catch {
            message.channel.send("Unknown error occurred.");
        }
    }
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
//msg is an instance of Message
const { guild } = msg;
await guild.channels.fetch();

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  const channel = await guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `channel${i}`)
  if (!channel) {
    //channel not found
  }
  if (channel.parentId !== 'CATEGORY_ID') {
    //not in the category
  }
}
```

This will check if the channel exists in the category.

This code will create the channel if it not found

```js
const { guild } = msg;
await guild.channels.fetch();

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  const channel = await guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `channel${i}`)
  if (!channel || channel.parentId !== 'categoryId') {
    guild.channels.create(`channel${i}`, { type: 'text' });
  }
}
```